# Error executing command: session while uninstalling a bundle in servicemix

Tags: java, apache-servicemix

following is the list of bundles I get when I run **list | grep -i context** in **Servicemix**

```
[  86] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   30] Spring Context (3.2.4.RELEASE)
[  87] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   30] Spring Context Support (3.2.4.RELEASE)
[ 288] [Installed  ] [            ] [       ] [   30] Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: spring-context (4.0.5.RELEASE_1)
[ 289] [Installed  ] [            ] [       ] [   30] Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: spring-context-support (4.0.5.RELEASE_1)
[ 371] [Installed  ] [            ] [       ] [   80] Spring Context (3.0.3.RELEASE)
[ 372] [Installed  ] [            ] [       ] [   80] Spring Context Support (3.0.3.RELEASE)
```

I can see that there are multiple versions of the same dependencies. So I wanted to un-install first 4 and just keep the last 2. everytime I try to stop or un-install any of the first 4, I'd get **Error executing command: session**.

Any insights?
thanks a lot.

**Command I ran and the output ::**

```
smx@root> stop 86
Error executing command: session
```

Full stacktrace ::

```
2014-10-15 13:21:35,032 | ERROR | Thread-90        | Console                          | ?                                     ? | 15 - org.apache.karaf.shell.console - 2.3.7 | Exception caught while executing command
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: session
at org.apache.karaf.shell.osgi.BundlesCommand.doExecute(BundlesCommand.java:43)
at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.OsgiCommandSupport.execute(OsgiCommandSupport.java:38)    [15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.7]
at org.apache.felix.gogo.commands.basic.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:35)   [15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.7]
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandProxy.execute(CommandProxy.java:78)[15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.7]
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:474)[     15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.7]
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:400)[15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.7]
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)[15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.7]
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:183)  [15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.7]
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:120)  [15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.7]
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:89) [15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.7]
at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline.Console.run(Console.java:184) [15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.7]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.7.0_65]
at org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh.ShellFactoryImpl$ShellImpl$4.doRun(ShellFactoryImpl.java:144) [37:org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh:2.3.7]
at org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh.ShellFactoryImpl$ShellImpl$4$1.run(ShellFactoryImpl.java:135)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)[:1.7.0_65]
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)[:1.7.0_65]
```

Comment: Are you sure there are no dependencies on these bundles? I assume they were deployed as part of your application, so removing them would result in multiple problems

Comment: the only dependencies required by the application are last two. first two came-up with the servicemix installation I guess. the mid-2 , I installed them accidently. the last two are the ones I wanna keep.

Comment: can you add following information to you question: what command do you execute and what error do you see in console